# Create new ParseUser using Google+ AccessToken returns InvalidSession?

Tags: android, google-plus, parse-platform

I'm trying to create a new ParseUser using a Google+ SignIn. While I'm able to retrieve the access token successfully from Google, I get a `ParseException(InvalidSession)`. 
I'll post a few snippets that are relevant.

**This is how im getting the AccessToken from Google**

```
final String SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login ";  
token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(
    MainActivity.this,
    Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient),
    "oauth2:" + SCOPES);
```

**Making ParseUser**

```
ParseUser.becomeInBackground(token, new LogInCallback()
{
    public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) 
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "makeParseUser"+"2");
        if (user != null)
        {
            // The current user is now set to user.
            /*
            user.put("name", s1);
            user.put("email",s6);
            user.saveInBackground();
            */
        }else 
        {
            // The token could not be validated.
            Log.i(TAG, "makeParseUser"+e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

A similar question has been asked [here](https://www.parse.com/questions/invalid-session-returned-from-becomeinbackground) but there doesn't seem to be a proper solution to it.

Comment: Where do you get the error?

Comment: Are you using the Google+ Access Token when calling ParseUser.becomeInBackground? This method expects a session token from Parse and not a third-party token. https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#users-become

Comment: @summers have you solved somehow?

Comment: @mvai Nop. Figured no body would use G+ anyway, not doing it

Answer (score 0):

Currently Parse doesn't support G+ login. Practically it can be done by using Parse cloud code.

`ParseUser.becomeInBackground();` expects Parse User token, but not G+ one.